How to full restore the metadata of the PieCloudDB data warehouse?
I am currently working with the PieCloudDB data warehouse and have encountered an issue where I need to full restore the metadata. I learned that the metadata layer of PieCloudDB is based on FoundationDB, but I don't know how to restore. Does anyone have experience with similar issues? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For the full restore metadata of PieCloudDB, the recommended solution is to restore the data to a new FoundationDB cluster. The steps are as follows:
1.After creating a new FoundationDB cluster, tenant information needs to be reconstructed based on the Tenant Map.
`\xff\xff/management/tenant_map/xxx01' is `{"id":0,"prefix":"\\u0000\\u0000\ \u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000"}' 
`\xff\xff/management/tenant_map/xxx02' is `{"id":1,"prefix":"\\u0000\\u0000\ \u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0001"}'

Tenants need to be re-created on the new FoundationDB in strict accordance with the order of IDs. The example is as follows:
fdbcli --exec "createtenant xxx01"
fdbcli --exec "createtenant xxx02"

2.Full restore FoundationDB data:
fdbrestore status -t ${tag_name} -r 'file://[backup_file_directory]' --dest-cluster-file [fdb_cluster_file_path_on_the_target_side]

You can also choose to restore only a certain FoundationDB tenant:
fdbrestore status -t ${tag_name} -r 'file://[backup_file_directory]' --dest-cluster-file [fdb_cluster_file_path_on_the_target_side] -k '[prefix_of_single_tenant]'

